# Unable to understand O(f(n))

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

What is the value of following recurrence:

T(n) = T(n/4) + T(n/2) + cn², T(1) = c, T(0) = 0

Where c is a positive constant:

1. T(n) = O(n³)
2. T(n) = O(n²)
3. T(n) = O(n² log n)
4. T(n) = O(n log n)

The correct answer is 2, but I have a doubt. According to the definition of O(f(n)) it gives us an upper bound, the O(n²) is the least upper bound. So in my opinion O(n³) and O(n² log n) should also be true.

Let

T(n) = 1/2n² + 3n

Which of the following statements are true (Check all that apply.)

1. T(n) = O(n)
2. T(n) = Ω(n)
3. T(n) = θ(n²)
4. T(n) = O(n³)

Here, the correct answers are 2, 3, and 4.

So, am I understanding the definition incorrectly or am I making some mistake?

Comment: You are correct that if T(n) = O(n^2), then A and C are true as well.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/algorithms-analysis-of-algorithms-question-1/  here on geeks it is given only B so i am confused

Comment: B would be right if the question asked which provided the *tightest* upper bound, but as worded A and C are equally correct.

Comment: Btw word " value " make any difference in first example?

Comment: I doubt it. It's not any standard way of asking for a tight upper bound that I am aware of. I think it's just a poorly worded question.

Comment: Yup the wordings are not clear, thanks again mate

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to prove [image: T(n) = O(n^2)] for the first recurrence using induction.
I'll use this definition of Big O (from [CLRS](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)):

[image: Big O Definition]

for some constants [image: k] and [image: n_0].

**Basis Step:**

[image: Basis Step]. Same for [image: T(0)], but since [image: T(0) = 0], it doesn't contribute anything to the recurrence and we can choose [image: T(1)] as our base case.

**Inductive Step:**

Assume [image: T(n/2) = O(n^2)], now deduce for [image: T(n)]. Since [image: T(n/4) <= T(n/2)], our assumption implies [image: T(n/4) = O(n^2)].

We have

[image: T(n/2) = O(n²) iff 0 < T(n/2) <= c<sub>1</sub>(n/2)^2]

for some constant [image: c_1].

Since

[image: Lemma]

holds, setting [image: x = T(n)] and [image: y_1, ..., y_n] to all the inductively assumed expressions yields:

[image: Algebraic Deduction]

[image: Q.E.D.]

<sub>(If I screwed up somewhere, let me know!)</sub>

> So in my opinion O(n³) and O(n² log n) should also be true.

[image: O(n^2) <= O(n^2 log n) <= O(n³) <= O(n^100)], so yes, you are entirely correct. You can prove it correct as done above. Informally, however, people often use [image: Big O] interchangeably with *tight* upper bound. It's imprecise, but customary. If you got those questions from a facility of higher learning, that's problematic, of course.

> So, am I understanding the definition incorrectly or am I making some
>   mistake?

You are basically correct. The real world isn't about formal correctness, though, so beware of informalisms and know better. As an aside, many people also treat the Landau symbols [image: Big O], [image: Big Omega], and [image: Big Theta] the same, even though they absolutely aren't.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely correct. I have done some more research on it, so in my opinion too  n^2, n^3, ....... all are correct and yes Thanks for explanation.

Comment: I think the above proof may be flawed, because the expansion series is not bounded by `n^2` if instead of `1/4` and `1/2` as the branching factors we had `a, b` such that `a + b > 1` or `a + b = 1`. I may be wrong though...

Comment: @meowgoesthedog If, as you say, a + b >= 1, then the problem isn't getting smaller but larger and there is no upper bound on T(n) because T(n) approaches infinity. It must be true that a + b < 1, otherwise such a recurrence does not describe the running time of an algorithm, which runs in finite time. Apart from that, it's not the case in my proof, so it certainly can't be a flaw.

Comment: @Downvoter that's only true if *either* of `|a|, |b| >= 1`, not for `a + b >= 1` and `|a|, |b| < 1`, because even the longest branch will still converge in this case. For the latter case it can be shown that there still exists a finite bound, with a geometric series form if the accumulated term is polynomial e.g. `n^2`.